# Как скрыть несколько файлов при перемещении Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, unix

У меня есть две папки images 1 & images2. В первой есть 10 файлов с разными расширениями, мне надо переместить с помощью маски все файлы кроме 3-4 в папку images2 при этом сделав их скрытыми.
Пробую :

`mv *[^3-4] /home/user/images2`

Но оно переносит все файлы из папки images1 в images2, никак не реагируя на [^3-4]

Как правильно перенести с помощью все файлы кроме 3-4 и при этом сделать их скрытыми?
Файлы в папке images1:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Имейте в виду, что в *nix нет понятия "скрытый файл" в терминах файловой системы. Другое дело, что чаще всего программы по умолчанию не показывают файлы, чьи имена начинаются с точки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*1222805.sh*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# File     : 1222805.sh
# Modified : <2020-12-23 Wed 11:34:36 GMT>
# URL      : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1222805/


mkdir --parents tmp/images1 tmp/images2

touch ./tmp/images1/file{1..10}.txt

tree ./tmp/

find ./tmp/images1 -type f -regex '[^3-4]+' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} mv {} ./tmp/images2/

tree ./tmp/

rm -rf ./tmp/*
```

```
chmod +x ./1222805.sh && ./1222805.sh
```

```
./tmp/
├── images1
│   ├── file10.txt
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   ├── file3.txt
│   ├── file4.txt
│   ├── file5.txt
│   ├── file6.txt
│   ├── file7.txt
│   ├── file8.txt
│   └── file9.txt
└── images2

2 directories, 10 files
./tmp/
├── images1
│   ├── file3.txt
│   └── file4.txt
└── images2
    ├── file10.txt
    ├── file1.txt
    ├── file2.txt
    ├── file5.txt
    ├── file6.txt
    ├── file7.txt
    ├── file8.txt
    └── file9.txt

2 directories, 10 files
```